# Sklearn inifinity value while doing kmeans clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to cluster over 200k points, by following:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
km.fit_transform(ends)
```

But I get the following error:
     km.fit_transform(ends)

So the matrix dimensions is `200kX2`

```
File "/Users/fleh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 814, in fit_transform
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
    ...
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

As far as I have been tracking the data.. the numbers are not that large.
How do i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What about NaNs? Try `np.nan_to_num(ends)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pandas for data handling, you can run this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(ends)
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
df.info()
```

The info() function will then tell you if you have any values that are non-computable.